How to combine multiple plots with a common continuous scale legend?
My dataframe is as follows:
dput(Book1)
structure(list(Phenotype = c("WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "WHR", 
"WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "WHR", 
"WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "BMI", "BMI", "BMI", 
"BMI", "BMI", "BMI", "BMI", "BMI", "BMI", "BMI", "BMI", "BMI", 
"BMI", "BMI", "BMI", "BMI", "BMI", "BMI", "BMI", "BMI", "BF", 
"BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", 
"BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "WC", "WC", "WC", 
"WC", "WC", "WC", "WC", "WC", "WC", "WC", "WC", "WC", "WC", "WC", 
"WC", "WC", "WC", "WC", "WC", "WC"), Feature = c("E1", "E2", 
"E3", "E4", "E5", "prs_add1", "prs_add2", "prs_add3", "prs_add4", 
"prs_add5", "prs_gxe1", "prs_gxe2", "prs_gxe3", "prs_gxe4", "prs_gxe5", 
"prs_gxe1.E1", "prs_gxe2.E2", "prs_gxe3.E3", "prs_gxe4.E4", "prs_gxe5.E5", 
"E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "prs_add1", "prs_add2", "prs_add3", 
"prs_add4", "prs_add5", "prs_gxe1", "prs_gxe2", "prs_gxe3", "prs_gxe4", 
"prs_gxe5", "prs_gxe1.E1", "prs_gxe2.E2", "prs_gxe3.E3", "prs_gxe4.E4", 
"prs_gxe5.E5", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "prs_add1", "prs_add2", 
"prs_add3", "prs_add4", "prs_add5", "prs_gxe1", "prs_gxe2", "prs_gxe3", 
"prs_gxe4", "prs_gxe5", "prs_gxe1.E1", "prs_gxe2.E2", "prs_gxe3.E3", 
"prs_gxe4.E4", "prs_gxe5.E5", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "prs_add1", 
"prs_add2", "prs_add3", "prs_add4", "prs_add5", "prs_gxe1", "prs_gxe2", 
"prs_gxe3", "prs_gxe4", "prs_gxe5", "prs_gxe1.E1", "prs_gxe2.E2", 
"prs_gxe3.E3", "prs_gxe4.E4", "prs_gxe5.E5"), Estimate = c(-0.046927378, 
0.021501452, -0.060576561, 0.026664695, 0.104747758, 0.07074638, 
0.023649159, NA, 0.032806854, 0.035131611, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.007299072, NA, NA, 0.011815316, 0.010481616, -0.05835143, NA, 
-0.08610439, NA, 0.06877879, 0.16459694, NA, 0.06961791, 0.03775922, 
NA, -0.01066025, NA, 0.01537474, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.01666013, 
0.02455695, 0.02196081, -0.047891691, NA, -0.095327227, 0.012395405, 
0.058295327, 0.096737663, NA, 0.047297343, 0.027082146, 0.032815238, 
-0.007341486, NA, 0.010720534, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.009458876, 0.014808779, 
0.011568591, -0.059678999, 0.013280999, -0.096726335, 0.021585317, 
0.10152862, 0.111473237, -0.003207717, 0.048416066, 0.026224904, 
0.038620466, -0.003613794, 0.001623824, 0.009766366, -0.002981712, 
0.002548997, NA, NA, 178.444778528, 390.731771843, 220.388712222
), pvalue = c(1.144351e-24, 4.80777e-07, 1.086296e-46, 7.993226e-07, 
2.285532e-85, 0.0003647517, 0.08261897, NA, 0.017708, 0.003835903, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.09759815, NA, NA, 0.02063316, 0.03890773, 
1.404994e-23, NA, 5.218511e-28, NA, 6.079532e-27, 1.217357e-08, 
NA, 0.001499233, 0.08749246, NA, 0.05960327, NA, 0.007881778, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0325944, 1.3024e-05, 0.0003457601, 5.504658e-28, 
NA, 2.312629e-48, 0.006481173, 1.458908e-38, 6.315281e-05, NA, 
0.001850213, 0.09934841, 0.03273855, 0.08196993, NA, 0.01139238, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.1444197, 0.0004105521, 0.005805464, 1.302842e-31, 
0.007986413, 7.798806e-46, 4.979966e-05, 8.837303e-83, 6.544795e-05, 
0.8587647, 0.004068312, 0.1263797, 0.01614415, 0.4730805, 0.743117, 
0.0488486, 0.5601606, 0.630477, NA, NA, 0.03294762, 4.632479e-07, 
0.00237151)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-80L))

My R code which is written to plot 1 of the 4 phenotypes (that is WHR, deleting all the entries related to BMI, BF and WC by features_df <- features_df[features_df$Phenotype=="WHR",]) in the above dataframe is as follows:
features_df <- Book1
features_df <- features_df[features_df$Phenotype=="WHR",]

# Create a new column with p-value intervals
features_df$p_interval <- cut(features_df$pvalue,
                         breaks = c(0, 0.0005, 0.005, 0.05, 1),
                         labels = c("< 0.0005", "0.005", "0.05", "1"),
                         include.lowest = TRUE)

# Define your custom legend values and sizes
legend_data <- data.frame(
  p_value_interval = c("< 0.0005", "0.005", "0.05", "1"),
  size = c(15,13,11,9)
)

library(dplyr)


# Adjust your dataframe by splitting the 'Feature' column more accurately
features_df <- features_df %>%
  mutate(
    Category = ifelse(grepl("prs_gxe\\d+\\.E\\d+$", Feature), "prs_gxe.E",
                      gsub("\\d+$", "", Feature)),  # Remove trailing digits generally, special case for prs_gxe.E
    Index = ifelse(grepl("prs_gxe\\d+\\.E\\d+$", Feature), sub("prs_gxe(\\d+)\\.E\\d+$", "\\1", Feature),
                   gsub("\\D+", "", Feature))  # Extract the number part, special handling for prs_gxe.E
  )


features_df <- features_df %>%
  mutate(Index = case_when(
    Index == 1 ~ "HD",
    Index == 2 ~ "NS",
    Index == 3 ~ "PA",
    Index == 4 ~ "PALC",
    TRUE ~ "SMK"  # Default case if none of the above conditions are met
  ))

features_df <- features_df %>%
  mutate(
    Category = case_when(
      Category == "prs_gxe.E" ~ "PRS[gxe]%*%E",   # Storing as character strings
      Category == "prs_gxe" ~ "'PRS'[gxe]",
      Category == "prs_add" ~ "'PRS'[add]",
      Category == "E" ~ "'E'",
      TRUE ~ Category  # Keeps other categories unchanged
    )
  )


library(ggplot2)
WHR <- ggplot(data = features_df, aes(x = Index, y = Category, fill = Estimate, size = p_interval)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white", fill = "white", size=1) +
  geom_point(shape = 22, color = "white", stroke = 0) +
  
  
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq_along(unique(features_df$Category)) + 0.5, color = "grey") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq_along(unique(features_df$Index)) + 0.5, color = "grey") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0.5, color = "grey")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, color = "grey")+
  geom_text(data = subset(features_df,(pvalue <= 0.05)&(pvalue > 0.005)),
            aes(label = "\u273B"),
            size = 4, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5,
            show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = subset(features_df, (pvalue <= 0.005)&(pvalue > 0.0005)),
            aes(label = "\u273B\u273B"),
            size = 4, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5,
            show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = subset(features_df, (pvalue <= 0.0005)),
            aes(label = "\u273B\u273B\u273B"),
            size = 4, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5,
            show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = subset(features_df, (is.na(Estimate))),
            aes(label = "NA"),
            size = 4, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5,
            show.legend = FALSE)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("red4", "white", "steelblue"),
                       limit = c(-max(abs(features_df$Estimate))-0.000, max(abs(features_df$Estimate))+0.000),
                       guide = guide_colorbar(title = "Estimate",
                                              label.position = "right",
                                              barwidth = 1,
                                              #barheight = 15,
                                              barheight = 10,
                                              title.position = "top",
                                              order = 1)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = legend_data$size,
                    breaks = legend_data$p_value_interval,
                    labels = legend_data$p_value_interval,
                    guide = guide_legend(title = "p value",
                                         label.position = "right",
                                         title.position = "top")) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = function(x) parse(text = x))+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,
                                   hjust = 1,
                                   vjust = 1,
                                   size = 12,
                                   colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, colour = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 0),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.1, "cm"),
        legend.key.height = unit(0.1, "cm"),
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0.2, "cm"),
        legend.position = "right",
        legend.box.margin = margin(b=-10, t=-10, l=-1, r=11),
        legend.box.just = ("center"),
        plot.margin = margin(b=20, t=20, l=20, r=20)) +
  labs(x = features_df$Phenotype, y = "", fill = "Estimate", size = "p value") +
  guides(size = guide_legend(reverse = F,
                             label.position = "right",
                             title.position = "top",
                             override.aes = list(colour="grey",
                                                 shape=15,
                                                 fill="white",
                                                 size=legend_data$size-1)))+
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 12))

WHR

This R code will give me the following plot:

My interest is to have a 2x2 all in one graph (for all the 4 phenotypes), using common Estimate and p value legends to all the four. I cannot graph the 4 plots separately because, when I combine them, I do not have a common legend. It is quite challenging to try options like grob given the complex nature of the code. Kindly help me to create the all in one plot (all phenotypes)

The code:
features_df <- Book1
###########################################features_df <- features_df[features_df$Phenotype=="WHR",]
# Create a new column with p-value intervals
features_df$p_interval <- cut(features_df$pvalue,
                         breaks = c(0, 0.0005, 0.005, 0.05, 1),
                         labels = c("< 0.0005", "0.005", "0.05", "1"),
                         include.lowest = TRUE)

# Define your custom legend values and sizes
legend_data <- data.frame(
  p_value_interval = c("< 0.0005", "0.005", "0.05", "1"),
  size = c(15,13,11,9)
)

library(dplyr)


# Adjust your dataframe by splitting the 'Feature' column more accurately
features_df <- features_df %>%
  mutate(
    Category = ifelse(grepl("prs_gxe\\d+\\.E\\d+$", Feature), "prs_gxe.E",
                      gsub("\\d+$", "", Feature)),  # Remove trailing digits generally, special case for prs_gxe.E
    Index = ifelse(grepl("prs_gxe\\d+\\.E\\d+$", Feature), sub("prs_gxe(\\d+)\\.E\\d+$", "\\1", Feature),
                   gsub("\\D+", "", Feature))  # Extract the number part, special handling for prs_gxe.E
  )


features_df <- features_df %>%
  mutate(Index = case_when(
    Index == 1 ~ "HD",
    Index == 2 ~ "NS",
    Index == 3 ~ "PA",
    Index == 4 ~ "PALC",
    TRUE ~ "SMK"  # Default case if none of the above conditions are met
  ))

features_df <- features_df %>%
  mutate(
    Category = case_when(
      Category == "prs_gxe.E" ~ "PRS[gxe]%*%E",   # Storing as character strings
      Category == "prs_gxe" ~ "'PRS'[gxe]",
      Category == "prs_add" ~ "'PRS'[add]",
      Category == "E" ~ "'E'",
      TRUE ~ Category  # Keeps other categories unchanged
    )
  )


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = features_df, aes(x = Index, y = Category, fill = Estimate, size = p_interval)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white", fill = "white", size=1) +
  geom_point(shape = 22, color = "white", stroke = 0) +
  
  
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq_along(unique(features_df$Category)) + 0.5, color = "grey") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq_along(unique(features_df$Index)) + 0.5, color = "grey") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0.5, color = "grey")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, color = "grey")+
  geom_text(data = subset(features_df,(pvalue <= 0.05)&(pvalue > 0.005)),
            aes(label = "\u273B"),
            size = 4, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5,
            show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = subset(features_df, (pvalue <= 0.005)&(pvalue > 0.0005)),
            aes(label = "\u273B\u273B"),
            size = 4, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5,
            show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = subset(features_df, (pvalue <= 0.0005)),
            aes(label = "\u273B\u273B\u273B"),
            size = 4, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5,
            show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = subset(features_df, (is.na(Estimate))),
            aes(label = "NA"),
            size = 4, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5,
            show.legend = FALSE)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("red4", "white", "steelblue"),
                       limit = c(-max(abs(features_df$Estimate))-0.000, max(abs(features_df$Estimate))+0.000),
                       guide = guide_colorbar(title = "Estimate",
                                              label.position = "right",
                                              barwidth = 1,
                                              #barheight = 15,
                                              barheight = 10,
                                              title.position = "top",
                                              order = 1)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = legend_data$size,
                    breaks = legend_data$p_value_interval,
                    labels = legend_data$p_value_interval,
                    guide = guide_legend(title = "p value",
                                         label.position = "right",
                                         title.position = "top")) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = function(x) parse(text = x))+
  facet_wrap(~Phenotype, ncol = 2) +###########################
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,
                                   hjust = 1,
                                   vjust = 1,
                                   size = 12,
                                   colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, colour = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 0),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.1, "cm"),
        legend.key.height = unit(0.1, "cm"),
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0.2, "cm"),
        legend.position = "right",
        legend.box.margin = margin(b=-10, t=-10, l=-1, r=11),
        legend.box.just = ("center"),
        plot.margin = margin(b=20, t=20, l=20, r=20)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "Estimate", size = "p value") +
  guides(size = guide_legend(reverse = F,
                             label.position = "right",
                             title.position = "top",
                             override.aes = list(colour="grey",
                                                 shape=15,
                                                 fill="white",
                                                 size=legend_data$size-1)))+
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 12))

Plot:

Here I have done the following edits:

Commented #features_df <- features_df[features_df$Phenotype=="WHR",]
Added  facet_wrap(~Phenotype, ncol = 2) + to divide the graphing area to 4 with 2 columns
Removed the x label labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "Estimate", size = "p value") +

